# Retrieving data in Table class CakePHP 3.2

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3.2
I am bit new to CakePHP. I am trying to get data from Icases table where the created date is within 10 days, but for some reason it's just returning the first row. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

My Controller IcasesController

```
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\AppController;

    /**
     * Icases Controller
     *
     * @property \App\Model\Table\IcasesTable $Icases
     */
    class IcasesController extends AppController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $case_count_data = $this->Icases->getCaseCountByAge();
            print_r($case_count_data);
        }
    }
```

My Table class IcasesTable

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use DateTime;

class IcasesTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('icases');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Clients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('Documents', [
            'foreignKey' => 'icase_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'icase_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinTable' => 'icases_users'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
                ->integer('id')
                ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_instruction_received')
                ->allowEmpty('date_instruction_received');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_online_invitation_last_sent')
                ->allowEmpty('date_online_invitation_last_sent');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_approved_for_allocation')
                ->allowEmpty('date_approved_for_allocation');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_consent_received')
                ->allowEmpty('date_consent_received');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('go_date')
                ->allowEmpty('go_date');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_last_referred_to_client')
                ->allowEmpty('date_last_referred_to_client');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_last_referred_to_qc_report')
                ->allowEmpty('date_last_referred_to_qc_report');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_last_referred_qc')
                ->allowEmpty('date_last_referred_qc');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_last_referred_sub')
                ->allowEmpty('date_last_referred_sub');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_last_state_change')
                ->allowEmpty('date_last_state_change');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_marked_for_archival')
                ->allowEmpty('date_marked_for_archival');

        $validator
                ->allowEmpty('state');

        $validator
                ->integer('weight')
                ->allowEmpty('weight');

        $validator
                ->requirePresence('case_reference_i_d', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('case_reference_i_d')
                ->add('case_reference_i_d', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

        $validator
                ->allowEmpty('special_intructions');

        $validator
                ->allowEmpty('international');

        $validator
                ->allowEmpty('name');

        $validator
                ->requirePresence('sms_enabled', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('sms_enabled');

        $validator
                ->allowEmpty('client_reference');

        $validator
                ->allowEmpty('position_applied_for');

        $validator
                ->integer('age')
                ->allowEmpty('age');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_deleted')
                ->allowEmpty('date_deleted');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_modified')
                ->allowEmpty('date_modified');

        $validator
                ->dateTime('date_created')
                ->requirePresence('date_created', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('date_created');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['case_reference_i_d']));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['client_id'], 'Clients'));

        return $rules;
    }

    /**
     * Gets Case count by age 0-10,10-15,15> days
     * @return Array ['count0to10'=>00,'count10to15'=>00,'count15'=>00]
     */
    public function getCaseCountByAge()
    {
        $casesTable = TableRegistry::get("Icases");

        $query = $casesTable->find("all",['condition'=>['Icases.date_created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')]]);
        $data = $query->execute();

        return $data->fetch('assoc');

    }
}
```

Comment: There is so much wrong in these few lines and I'm honestly to lazy to explain it. Please, just do the blog tutorial and read about the ORM, it's query builder and custom finders in the official documentation: http://book.cakephp.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read and practice more according to [CakePHP official Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html)

```
public function getCaseCountByAge()
{
    $casesTable = TableRegistry::get("Icases");

    $query = $casesTable->find("all",['condition'=>['Icases.date_created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')]]);
    $data = $query->execute();

    return $data->fetch('assoc');

}
```

It could be very simple

```
public function getCaseCountByAge()
    {
        return $this->find("all",['condition'=>['Icases.date_created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')]])->all();
    }
```